# Microsoft Graph : Get witch groups a user is member of

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a group that I am member of och I will get the group in my C# app and Graph by:

```
  ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

 var groups2 = await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "mail eq 'IntranetTest365@xxx.se'";

                });
```

Looking at DisplayName and Mail I got the right group.

But the members is null.

The AAD for the app has several Graphrights. For example:
GroupMember.Read.All
I am self a member of the group.

So, how can I get the members of the group and why is members null?

Changeing the rights. Checking excpetion and could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

I have one Azure AD group named **`Demo`** with below group members:

[image]

When I ran below graph query in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by filtering with mail, I too got **null results** for members:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=mail+eq+'demo@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'+&$select=displayName,mail,members
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you need to use **`$expand`** parameter in the query to get
> members of group. To **confirm** that, you can check this [**MS
> Doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships:%7E:text=$expand.-,members,-directoryObject%20collection) for reference.

When I ran below modified query by including **`$expand`** parameter, I got **group members** too in response like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=mail+eq+'demo@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'+&$select=displayName,mail,members&$expand=members($select=id,displayName)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To get the same via code, I registered one Azure AD application and granted below **API permissions** in it:

[image]

Now, I ran below c# code to get **group member**s Ids in the response like below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
using Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors;
using System;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var clientId = "appId";
var tenantId = "tenantID";
var clientSecret = "secret";

var options = new ClientSecretCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

try
{
    var result = await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "mail eq 'demo@M365x56209219.onmicrosoft.com' ";
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName", "mail", "members" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Expand = new string[] { "members" };
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Group info:");
    foreach(var group in result.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(group.DisplayName);
        Console.WriteLine(group.Mail);
        Console.WriteLine("\nGroup Members:");
        foreach (var member in group.Members)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(member.Id);
        }
    }

}

catch (ODataError odataError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Code);
    Console.WriteLine(odataError.Error.Message);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, will try it out today.